# What is the ultra wormhole shiny rate for Pokémon ultra sun and ultra moon

Tags: pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon

In the new Pokémon ultra sun and ultra moon game, they added the ultra wormhole shiny hunting method. They say that your shiny chance increases after 3000 light years, but how much does it increase for every 1000 light year?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the information on [Serebii](https://www.serebii.net/ultrasunultramoon/ultrawormholes.shtml), the chances of finding a shiny increases by both light years and the type of ultra wormhole you use.

> Another thing that changes as you progress through further Light Years is the chance of encountering a Shiny Pokémon. The further you go, the higher the chance is that the Pokémon you will get is a Shiny Pokémon and the wormhole also factors in capping at 5,000 Light Years at 36% in the Type 4 Wormholes.

The formulas below are the chances of finding a shiny by wormhole type

**Type 1**

> 1%; Top Rarity: 1%

**Type 2**

> 1+(min(9,((LightYear/500)-1))%; Top Rarity: 10%

**Type 3**

> 1+2(min(9,((LightYear/500)-1))%; Top Rarity: 19%

**Type 4**

> 4(min(9,((LightYear/500)-1))%; Top Rarity: 36%

So using 1000 light years, the percentage chance of finding a shiny can be calculated to:

1. Type 1: 1%
2. Type 2: 2%
3. Type 3: 3%
4. Type 4: 4%